# MVC4 Custom View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having issues implementing a MVC4 Custom View Engine to override the default locations for partial views.  I have implemented the code in this [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx).

My issue is that an error is thrown before CreatePartialView is initiated if the path does not match a value in PartialViewLocationFormats array when HTML.Partial is initiated/executed.  Nothing is going to match as the objective of this implementation is to have dynamic paths.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just supply the path by your own way instead of using the default way that MVC to 
set partialPath  from another source such as passing it to view from controller , or creating your view  finder class .

```
return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, **partialPath** );
```